# Java build a tree from ResultSet thats returnable as auto-json through Spring

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm sure this can be done with additional wrapper classes but I'm trying to learn an efficient way to do this:

Sample rows

```
Country | State | City        | Zip
USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11210
USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11211
USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11212
USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11213
USA     |  NY   | Bronx       | 10450
USA     |  NY   | Bronx       | 10451
USA     |  NY   | Bronx       | 10452
USA     |  NJ   | Jersey City | 07310
USA     |  NJ   | Jersey City | 07311
Canada  |  ON   | Keswick     | L4P 4K3
```

I have a Spring API endpoint:

```java
@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity</*Whatever makes sense*/> getAllAddress() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(server.getAllAddresses()); // select * from addresses as ResultSet
}
```

**What would be an optimal way to generate nested Json arrays, something to the following effect:**

```
{
"addresses": { 
      "USA": [ {
         "NY" : [ {
           "Brooklyn" :  [ 11210, 11211, 11212, 11213],
           "Bronx"    :  [ 10450, 10451, 10452]
          } ]
         "NJ" : [ {

           ...etc
}
```

Thank you.

(I'm using addresses as an example - my program is different column names but same structure many string to many string to many string to many string)

Comment: I request this to be reopened.  I'm asking for an efficient way to generate output.  Not 'whats the best' or 'whats the most optimal'.  If something else is screaming 'opinion based question' then by all means please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream your line, then collect them using nested `Collectors.groupingBy`. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11210\n" +
                "USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11211\n" +
                "USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11212\n" +
                "USA     |  NY   | Brooklyn    | 11213\n" +
                "USA     |  NY   | Bronx       | 10450\n" +
                "USA     |  NY   | Bronx       | 10451\n" +
                "USA     |  NY   | Bronx       | 10452\n" +
                "USA     |  NJ   | Jersey City | 07310\n" +
                "USA     |  NJ   | Jersey City | 07311\n" +
                "Canada  |  ON   | Keswick     | L4P 4K3";
        List<String[]> lines = Arrays.stream(data.split("\n"))
                .map(line -> line.split("\\|"))
                .map(lineParts -> Arrays.stream(lineParts).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String[]>>>> nestedMap = lines.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                line -> line[0],
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        line -> line[1],
                        Collectors.groupingBy(line -> line[2])
                )
        ));

        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        String json = jsonb.toJson(nestedMap);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

Would ouput that:

```
{
  "Canada": {
    "ON": {
      "Keswick": [
        [
          "Canada",
          "ON",
          "Keswick",
          "L4P 4K3"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "USA": {
    "NY": {
      "Brooklyn": [
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Brooklyn",
          "11210"
        ],
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Brooklyn",
          "11211"
        ],
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Brooklyn",
          "11212"
        ],
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Brooklyn",
          "11213"
        ]
      ],
      "Bronx": [
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Bronx",
          "10450"
        ],
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Bronx",
          "10451"
        ],
        [
          "USA",
          "NY",
          "Bronx",
          "10452"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "NJ": {
      "Jersey City": [
        [
          "USA",
          "NJ",
          "Jersey City",
          "07310"
        ],
        [
          "USA",
          "NJ",
          "Jersey City",
          "07311"
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: They are not text line.... They are database records......

Comment: Assuming I have a list of Objects that I can call getXyz() for each key, should this solution work (rather then list of strings)?  I'm not able to adjust the syntax so far...

Comment: of course. `(List<MyModel>).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyModel::getX, Collectors.groupingBy(MyModel::getY))`